Wavesurfer.js - looking for a way to split channels but also to be able to manipulate each channel
Im using wavesurferjs library to handle my waveforms. https://wavesurfer.xyz/
What Im trying to do now is to stack a couple of waveforms on each other, or just simply render a couple of channels in one audio (in one waveform instance). I found in the docs info about splitting channels, but I wonder if this is what im looking for. I need to be able to change volume of only e.g. Vocals or Bass. Please take a look at attached gif. This is what Im trying to achieve.
What I tried is to use that split channel, but the waveform is not appearing and I guess Im not able to change volume of each channel because there's no way to get to the each channel separately.
const ws = WaveSurfer.create({
    backend: 'MediaElement',
    container: '#container',
    splitChannels: [
      {
        peaks: [//peaks here],
        container: '#container',
        waveColor: 'yellow',
        progressColor: 'lightyellow',
        backend: 'MediaElement',
        url: 'url_to_the_bass_file',
      },
      {
        peaks: [//peaks here],
        container: '#container',
        waveColor: 'blue',
        progressColor: 'lightblue',
        backend: 'MediaElement',
        url: 'url_to_the_vocals_file',
      },
    ],
  })

// how to set volume of each channel? is it even possible?

Looking forward for any help or hint.
On the gif is what Im trying to achieve. To be able to stack channels and manipulate their volume. Source: https://www.bandlab.com/splitter

